# WinForms (.NET Framework) doesn't seem to notice DPI sessions between RDP sessions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

It seems that, in the following scenario, Windows Forms won't notice a DPI change without a restart of the app:

1. connect to an RDP session
2. launch the app
3. disconnect; reconnect, but with a different DPI setting in the RDP client

This seems to be because in such a scenario, Windows never sends [`WM_DPICHANGED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/wm-dpichanged) (as of Windows 11 22000.194, anyway), and [that seems to be](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,5156) the only way Windows Forms notices changes.

Windows *does* send [`WM_DISPLAYCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-displaychange), though, which includes the new DPI.

From decompiling WinForms, it seems I *could* listen to that message and construct my own `DpiChangedEventArgs` to have controls notice the change.

Before I endeavour on that,

- can someone confirm this behavior? There are probably other scenarios it applies to? (i.e., a display gets disconnected, then on reconnect has a different DPI, and WinForms doesn't notice as a result)
- is there a nicer fix I'm missing, other than to send the event myself?

Comment: What version of .NET Framework or .NET (Core)? Are you certain your app has opted into being DPI-aware as per https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#configuring-your-windows-forms-app-for-high-dpi-support ?

Comment: (.NET Framework 4.8, and yeah, I did — like I said, it does notice changes while the session is open.) But now that you mention it, I've made a _fresh_ .NET Framework 4.8 app and there it works even with reconnects. Odd.